# Laravel, sync data with Pivot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot

Laravel 5.3, I have this 2 models:

User:

```
public function newFunctions()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\NewFunctions', 'user_newfunctions')
        ->withPivot(['function_count', 'days_count']);
}
```

NewFunctions:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_newfunctions', 'new_function_id', 'user_id')
        ->withPivot(['function_count', 'days_count']);
}
```

I now how can I save new data to User, with this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->save();
```

But now I have to update some values of a pivot table. the pivot table is this:

```
user_id | new_functions_id | function_count | days_count
---------------------------------------------------------
    814 |           1      |   5            |2019-07-19 12:26:19
    814 |           3      |   7            |2019-07-19 12:26:19
```

I have more than 1 row per `user_id`. I was trying to use:

```
$user
    ->newFunctions()
    ->sync([
        'days_count' => $test_date,
        'function_count' => $test_int_number
    ]);
```

But I'm getting error like:

> Ilegal offset type

because is trying to update with this:

```
array(
    'records' => array(
        'days_count' => object(Carbon), 'function_count' => '66'),
        'results' => array(),
        'id' => object(Carbon),
        'attributes' => array()

    )
)

in BelongsToMany.php
```

So:

- How could I update the values for each user_id on the pivot table?
- And how should use `sync`to update just 'function_count' and 'days_count'? they come from request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->sync()` isn't used like that; it's used to `attach()` and `detach()` related `new_function_ids` until only the `ids` in `sync()` are present. You're probably looking for `updateExistingPivot()`

An example of `->sync()` would be using the array:

```
$user->newFunctions()->sync([
    "new_function_id" => 1,
    "function_count" => 6,
    "days_count" => "2019-07-08 12:00:00",
]);
```

This would remove the record where `new_function_id` is `3`, and updating the values where `new_function_id` is `1`.

To update `function_count` and `days_count` for either `new_function_id` of `1` or `3`, use `->updateExistingPivot()` (pass the `id` you want to update as the first parameter):

```
$user
    ->newFunctions()
    ->updateExistingPivot("1", [
        "function_count" => 6,
        "days_count" = "2019-07-08 12:00:00"
    ]);
// or $user->newFunctions()->updateExistingPivot("3", ...);
```

This will update the pivot table where `new_function_id` is `1`, while leaving the row where `new_function_id` is `3`.

Edit: If you're looking to update all existing records in the pivot table, you'll need to do this in a loop, call a sync with all current records in a single array, or run a manual query.

Comment: Do you like chocolates, wine? I will send you a gift, seriously.

Comment: Haha that's ok; appreciate the sentiment though. Cheers!

Comment: I'll catch you on Linkedin and I'll send you a wine from Chile, best wine of the world,